# Array is stored as string. How do I convert it back to any array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, redis

I am using Rails 4.2 with Redis.  When I store and retrieve an array with Redis, it returns a formatted string.  How do I return this string to an array?

The returned string is exactly this, though the number and value of entries will obviously vary:

```
"[\"FCF1115A\", \"FCF1116A\"]"
```

Obviously, it could be parsed, but is there some function that would handle this?   I could probably format a better string myself, rather than allowing Redis to do so.  Thanks...

Comment: Can you show us the code for how you're retrieving the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using [JSON](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) library is an option.  Following is tested in `irb`:

```
> require 'json'
> puts JSON.parse("[\"FCF1115A\", \"FCF1116A\"]").to_json
=> ["FCF1115A","FCF1116A"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It looks good too, however I decided to use YAML as follows: YAML.load("[\"FCF1115A\", \" FCF1116A \"]".delete ': ')